# Можно ли использовать один API Controller для всех моделей?

Tags: веб-программирование, api, asp.net-core, .netcore2.0

Я хочу создать api для веб приложения **на asp.net core 2.0** . И когда я хочу добавить api контроллер с использованием Entity Framwork она просить выбрать конкретный модель(у меня там Items, Users, Posts etc.) И вот мне нужно создать api контроллер на каждую модель отдельно или  все же можно создать один для всех ??? И правильно ли обрабатывать все модели одним api контроллером ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял вы хотите все запихнуть в один класс? Вообще так делать не стоит. По факту вы можете какие угодно модели обрабатывать в апиконтроллере одновременно. Просто вы ограничены в методах Get, Post, Put, Delete. Они должны быть максимально одинарны, ну может пару Get. Так что я б вам рекомендовал для каждой группы базы данных делать свой апиконтроллер.  Если у ж вам так хочется, то сделайте универсальную модель для вьюхи UniversalViewModel и запихните туда все свойства и уже кодом пишите сколько угодно костылей, но как по мне это плохо.